# How to eliminate multiple click functions?

Tags: jquery, code-cleanup

Does anyone know a way to streamline my abundance of click functions?

Here is my example:

```
$("#info01_v1_btn").click(function(){
    $("#info01_v1").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#info01_v1_btn a").toggleClass("open");
    return false;
});

$("#info02_v1_btn").click(function(){
    $("#info02_v1").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#info02_v1_btn a").toggleClass("open");
    return false;
});

$("#info03_v1_btn").click(function(){
    $("#info03_v1").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#info03_v1_btn a").toggleClass("open");
    return false;
});

$("#info04_v1_btn").click(function(){
    $("#info04_v1").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#info04_v1_btn a").toggleClass("open");
    return false;
});

$("#info05_v1_btn").click(function(){
    $("#info05_v1").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#info05_v1_btn a").toggleClass("open");
    return false;
});
```

If theses functions weren't being called on the same page together I'd probably just use a class instead of an id, but I'm using a module that's housing multiple address info so not sure how else to do it. For the record, this works, just seems really messing. Not sure if adding a loop would help clean it up or not.

Note*:I'm a web designer and self taught jquery'ier, so looking for any good techniques to make this code smaller any potentially reusable elsewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".YourClassName").click(function(){
    var t = $(this).attr('id').replace('_btn','');
    $( '#' + t ).slideToggle("fast");    
    $(this).find('a').toggleClass("open");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This worked great! I had actually already built some queries within my design using #info01_v2_btn, #info02_v2_btn, #info03_v2_btn, etc. and this solution still works great! 82 lines of code into 6 ...beauty!

Comment: @JosephSjoblom if you are using jquery 1.7.2or above you can use the top answer as well, it's basically the same thing, EDIT - sorry nvm, if you have v2 it would not work

Answer (score 3):

Bind the event to all elements ending with `_v1_btn`, and use the ID to target the next element and the `this` keyword to find the `<a>` element you need  to target :

```
$('[id$="_v1_btn"]').on('click', function(){
    var ID = this.id.replace('_btn', '');
    $("#"+ID).slideToggle("fast");
    $('a', this).toggleClass("open");
    return false;
});
```